# Create ReactiveX observable in Java 6 without lambda expression

Tags: java, rx-java, reactivex

I found an example for how to create an observable object (ReactiveX):

```
static Observable<Integer> getDataSync(int i) {
        return Observable.create((Subscriber<? super Integer> s) -> {
            // simulate latency
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                s.onNext(i);
                s.onCompleted();
            });
    }
```

But my project does not support Java 8 for lambda expression. I couldn't find example of how to use ReactiveX observable without lambda expression.

Comment: Reactive? Do you mean "Observer"? http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077258/learn-java/observer-and-observable.html

Comment: Most modern IDE will have the option to convert to anonymous inner class if you write a lambda in a Java 6 project.

Comment: Im using intellij but i couldn't find how do it.. Do you have experience with it ?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse, there is a quick fix for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you just looking for the correct lambda-less syntax for what you are doing?

That would be:

```
static Observable<Integer> getDataSync(int i) {
    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Integer> {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super Integer> s) {
            // simulate latency
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            s.onNext(i);
            s.onCompleted();
        }
    });
}
```